# What bottled water?

Tags: water

I am going to use bottled water so I do not have to worry about the tap one beeing not too clear (Here I can find some at 0.20-0.30 $ a liter). Since bottled water has information on minerals in the water I want to take advantage of that. Which mineral should be there and which shouldn't be? What about pH or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target **mash** PH is between 5.1 and 5.5 (again, not the water PH, the mash).
From that comes that depending on what you are brewing you **may** need to make different mineral adjustments to reach the target PH. You may also want to try to emulate the water of a region that produces the style of beer you are brewing.
John Palmer explained it all very nicely on [his book](http://www.howtobrew.com/section3/chapter15.html)